# How to restrict openvpn clients to communicate with other vpn clients

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, openvpn

I have this Openvpn scenario..

I have Lot of openvpn clients connected to my server, All i want is to restrict client to client communication.

for eg. i have (10.20.0.2,10.20.0.3,10.20.0.4,10.20.0.5) clients 
10.20.0.2 should not talk to 10.20.0.3 or 4, 5

Is there any way to achieve this using iptables? or through editing Configuration file?

Comment: You can disable `client-to-client` in your server configuration. If it is disabled each client should see only the server. Check [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage).